# make --version command returning string of seemingly random characters and write error

Tags: gnu-make

I'm trying to check the version of Make via command prompt and when I run `make --version`, the command just returns

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
?±?e?I?t???[?\?t?g?E?F?A?A?・. ???p??‘o?E?A?￠?A?I?\?[?X?d
?2???-???3?￠.
???A?≪?a“A’e?I?U“I?O?I“K?‡?≪?I”@‰??E?O?i?c?，, ?3?U?O?A?・.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
make: write error
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you running it on Windows? Can you check another terminal?

Comment: Are you running it in a cmd.exe shell?  Powershell?  bash shell?  What is the value of your locale environment variables?  Looks to me like maybe you have set a language that uses a character set that your terminal doesn't provide support for.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I was running it on Windows Command Prompt. I just ran it through Powershell and got the exact same output.

Comment: @MadScientist I don't know what you mean by locale environment variables, but I do have MsAppLocale installed and set to Japanese for certain games on my computer. Would that be causing the issue? If so, how do I solve it?

Comment: I don't know much about Windows and I don't know anything about MsAppLocale.  You can try adding `set LC_ALL=C` and `set LANG=C` at your shell prompt before running `make` and see if it helps.  Or, you can try deleting the various translations from your installed make instance (I don't know what you're using or where you got it so I can't help with that).  Or, maybe it's something totally different.

Comment: @MadScientist So I tried using `set LC_ALL = C` but it had no effect. 

I don't really understand why it would interfere with Make, though, since I never set Make to run in that locale. It was a very specific game that I downloaded MsAppLocale for and applied it to (you have to select the EXE file in the prompt window) so it shouldn't be affecting Make.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: make is not a separate application like a game.  It basically inherits the locale information from the shell.  I have no idea either, but the only way I can imagine that you would get the output you show is if it were trying to print output using a character set that the terminal doesn't support so instead of characters in some other language, it shows as garbage.  But maybe you should try downloading and using a newer version of GNU make (as you can see 3.81 is 16 years old), or even compiling it yourself if you have a C compiler installed.

Comment: @MadScientist I guess the older version was the issue? I just deleted the whole folder and installed Make 4.3 from elsewhere, so now that's been resolved. Thank you so much!